# How does the difference in energy levels decrease as you increase $n$ in 1D particle in a box (correspondence principle)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation

I found from multiple sources that the difference between energy levels must decrease as you increase quantum numbers in order to follow the correspondence principle. The energy of a particle in the box increases proportionally to $n$-squared. This means that the energy spacings increase at high values of $n$. How does the correspondence principle is applicable with respect to energy level differences?

Comment: what are the sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea that the difference between energy levels must decrease as you increase the quantum number in order to recover the [correspondence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle) must be wrong: if it were true, then the quantum harmonic oscillator could not exist in the physical world. What we may require is the fact that the *relative* energy difference must decrease as a function of $n$. Relative to what? Well, relative to the macroscopic energy of the system $E(n)$. We therefore postulate:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \Delta_r(n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{E(n+1)-E(n)}{E(n)}=0.
$$
If this is true, then for high $n$ (classical limit) increasing the energy quantum number does not produce an appreciable energy difference, at least if compared to the macroscopic energy $E(n)$ we experience. In other words, we lose track of the discreteness of the energy levels of $E(n)$.

Note that for the case of the particle in a 1D box we have $E(n)=\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL^2}$, where $m$ is the particle mass and $L$ the box length. Hence, $\Delta_r(n)=(2n+1)/n^2$, which correctly vanishes when $n$ goes to infinity. In contrast, a physical system with energy dependence $E(n)= E_0 e^n$ would display quantum effects in the macroscopic world, since $\Delta_r(n)=e-1$. As far as I know, however, we still haven't found such a quantum system and the classical limit is always recovered.

Comment: It's worth noting that quantum effects are *everywhere*.  An immediate example is the opacity or transparency of solids to visible light, which arises because the electron energy states inside a solid can be interrupted by band gaps which don't shrink to zero in the thermodynamic limit.

Comment: You are absolutely right, and indeed the correspondence principle shouldn't be taken as a universal guiding law separating the classical and quantum world. However, I believe the naive way I have presented it can be considered quite universal. Better said, if we found a system for which $\Delta_r(n)$ does not vanish for large $n$, we would observe some really weird quantum effect in the macroscopic world, different from the rest of everyday phenomena that only quantum mechanics can explain.

Comment: Well, that was my point about the energy bands - in the thermodynamic limit, the spacing between energy levels vanishes *within each band*, but the top of one band and the bottom of the next are adjacent states which are separated by a non-vanishing $\Delta$.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your point, but I would argue that the failure of a system to exhibit universal $\Delta_r(n)\rightarrow 0$ behavior is one of the key indicators that the system cannot be accurately modeled using a purely classical treatment.

Comment: I see. Definitely the energy gap between different bands is a purely quantum feature of the macroscopic world. However, I am not sure if we can read it as a failure of the correspondence principle as I introduced it above: there $n$ indicates the quantum number and not the number of particles, so that $n\rightarrow\infty$ does not correspond to the thermodynamic limit. In your case, $n$ would better label each different band. Are you saying that $\Delta_r(n)$ does not go to zero even when considering the energy gap between the $n$th and $n+1$th bands?

Comment: The energy of an electronic state in a crystal is a function of the band index $n$ and the crystal momentum $\mathbf k$.  The number of different $\mathbf k$'s in each band is (essentially) given by the number of atoms in the crystal; in the thermodynamic limit, this number goes to infinity and the energy spacing between different $\mathbf k$'s in the same band goes to zero.  However, the energy difference between the highest energy state in band $n$ and the lowest energy state in band $n+1$ does not vanish in the thermodynamic limit, nor does it go to zero with increasing $n$.

Comment: That being said, the index of the highest occupied band is related to which period of the periodic table the atoms comprising the solid are in.  In macroscopic solids, the valence band index might be in the range 1-10 or so, but it certainly isn't the $n\rightarrow \infty$ limit.

Comment: Yes, I see your point, but $\Delta_r(n)$ is normalized by the energy of the $n$th band. If $\Delta E(n)$ is the energy gap between the $n$th and $n+1$th bands, and $E(n)$ is the "top" energy of the $n$th band (we forget about $\mathbf{k}$ in the thermodinamic limit), then we have $\Delta_r(n)=\Delta E(n)/E(n)$. If it doesn't vanish for $n\rightarrow \infty$, then the gap between different bands must increase exponentially.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117524/discussion-between-j-murray-and-goffredo-gretzky).